# div section not displaying across all pages

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag which is not displaying across all pages on my website. It was working fine before now and all of a sudden it stopped. The website address is [fudmonga.org](https://fudmonga.org).

Below is the html code for the homepage

```
<div class="block-31" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="owl-carousel loop-block-31 ">
      <div class="block-30 item" style="background-image: url('images/img1.jpg');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <h2 class="heading">...tackling hunger, one person at a time!</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Help visit the website to inspect the styles

Comment: can you add screenshot too ! Which part you want to fix

Comment: Which of the divs are we talking about? There are six in this little snippet alone. And what does the inspector of your browser say the differences are?

Comment: When I look up your site , it have many console error . May be because of that error so fixing that is a better option ...

Comment: @DavidJapan How do i check this errors?

Comment: goes to your site and click f12 then see in `console` tab